# Definition of the term "value" in C standard

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards

In C standard (N2176),

> **3.19**
>
> **value**
>
> precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type

So I thought that the term "value" is only applicable to an object. However, I also think that an expression may be evaluated to a "value" that is not an object, e.g., `1 + 3`. What is the definition of the computation result of an expression? Is it a value (the definition of a value should be extended) or some other term?

Comment: the result of the expression will be stored in an object, right? Which will have a value.

Comment: Are you claiming that `1+3` is a value?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes. I think `1+3` is a valid expression and has a value of `4`. Am I wrong?

Comment: I expect we are intended to take 3.19 as **a** definition of “value” when it is used in a context appropriate for that definition, not as **the** only definition of “value.” In other words, in addition to this technical definition for the value of an object, it retains its ordinary meaning in other contexts, such as values used in expressions.

Comment: "expression" is not the same as "value" (which is why they are different words).

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, the expression itself is not a value, but evaluation of the expression produces a value, and the value is not the value of any object and cannot be the value as defined in 3.19. The C standard has numerous uses of the word “value” throughout that cannot be this meaning in 3.19.

Comment: @ScottHunter But an expression "has" a value (not "is" a value) which is the result of its evaluation.

Comment: The constant `1` is not an object, and its evaluation does not need to produce one, but it has a value.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. [6.2.6.1 General p. 8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p8) says a weird thing: «Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation, which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result», which reads as that operators are using object representations of values, not values themselves.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don't see how it is related to what I said. Is `1` an object? Nope. Does it have a value? Yep. There are one or more object representations of this value. So?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ah, I was thinking about `1` in the context of `1 + 3` from the question. Since the paragraph says _«object representation is **used**»_ (by an operator) and p.4 says _«The value may be copied into an object of type `unsigned char [n]` (e.g., by `memcpy`); the resulting set of bytes is called the object representation of the value»_, then in `1 + 3`, to use object representations, the operator needs to copy the values into objects of type `unsigned char [sizeof(int)]`; which means an object is produced for `1`. For `1` alone, I think you are right.